# Numpy: Apply vectorized function to part of array

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm a Numpy newbie.

I have a vectorized function `np.vectorize(my_function)` and I'd like to apply it to a big array `x`.

I'm trying to parallelize it, so my idea is to spawn 8 processes, and let them work on 8 equal parts of the array. Of course, I'd like to avoid as much copying as I can, to keep it as fast as possible.

I was thinking, I'll use Python's new [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) feature to make the array accessible to all processes without having to pickle it.

The pickle is, I wouldn't know how to apply `np.vectorize(my_function)` in the worker process to a part of the array. I want to tell it, "Take this array with 1,000,000 members, and please run it on the slice of members 200,000 to 300,000, but *without* creating a new input array for that slice."

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you see `np.vectorize` disclaimer, that it is not a speed tool?  That `shared memory` is too new to expect much experience from us.

Comment: Before getting into multiprocessing and worrying about copies, make sure your function makes optimal use of existing whole-array methods.  If your function can only work with scalar inputs, then consider iterating on a list.  It will be faster than using `np.vectorize`.  `np.vectorize` is a convenience when dealing with several array inputs that need to be broadcast against each other, but for one 1d array it doesn't do much for you.

Comment: If you have a function that takes a 1d array, and returns another, you can subdivide the task by working with slices: e.g. `res[i: j] = f( arr[i : j])`.  A slice of an array is a `view`, and thus is quite efficient.  However internally `f()` might make a copy of its input, and of course the result will be a new array. And assigning that array to a slice of target `res` array will require copying.